# Interface Microsoft Access to Drupal database

Tags: entities

I am wondering if anyone has ever succeeded in editing their Drupal database with Microsoft Access.

I have already figured out how to use Oracle's Mysql ODBC connector to enable MS Access to see my Drupal database. What I would like to do now is use the well-developed capabilities of MS Access to edit a few tables.

I am not interested in centrally important Drupal tables like node or user, but would be interested in editing a crm_core_contact table. More specifically, if I wanted to add a contact entity to a crm_core_contact table, would I be able to generate the uuid in MS Access, or do uuids in Drupal need to be generated by Drupal?

Could someone tell me if all of this is absolute heresy, a really bad idea, or a potentially intriguing possibility?

The first two comments below were helpful.  Responding:  (1) The reason for using MS Access rather than the Drupal database API is the ease of creating a user interface.  I've used Access for years, and it will be much easier to create Forms, Macros, etc. in Access than it will be to write PHP script to do the same thing.  As for (2), Clive's response is exactly what I was looking for.  I would like, though, to know more about the difficulties that I would run in to.  I'm not expecting anyone to do a tutorial for me, but is there documentation somewhere that describes what it takes to modify (or add) an entity?  It requires very few lines of code to create an entity and to use the entity_metadata_wrapper interface to populate it.  So is there a place that describes what is going on "behind the scenes" so that I could directly do this?

Comment: I’m not sure why this has to be done with MS Access, the Drupal database api is fairly robust to handle this in a minimal amount of code.

Comment: It's not "heresy", but probably getting into the "really bad idea" column. Creating/updating an entity is more complicated than just manipulating the base table directly; hooks run, caches are invalidated, revisions created, etc. It's all data at the end of the day, so it's technically possible, but it's not going to be easy to create a robust solution

Comment: A "simple" $entity->save() could result in several thousand lines of code firing. Exactly what happens very much depends on how the entity is defined and configured and what modules are installed on the site. You are not likely to find a tutorial that covers the subject in depth.